# Adding svg pattern to border-image property

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting to add an SVG pattern to the bottom border of my DIV element. The approach i've taken is not working. [Here is the code so far.](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/KrOwXb). This is where I created the [SVG pattern](http://www.patternify.com/). Lastly this is [image: type of effect] i'm trying to create in CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pattern">
   hello
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pattern{
  color:white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-image:url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAP0lEQVQYV2P8////f0ZGRkYGAgCsgBjFcJMIKUaxEp9iDLfhUoxVIcjd6B7E6Vt0k/EGC7JiguEHU0xQISycASOfKAejj1tDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
  )repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use the `:after` pseudo element to create the same effect:

```
.pattern{
  color:white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pattern:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:url( data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAP0lEQVQYV2P8////f0ZGRkYGAgCsgBjFcJMIKUaxEp9iDLfhUoxVIcjd6B7E6Vt0k/EGC7JiguEHU0xQISycASOfKAejj1tDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
  );
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Hi. This worked! and is actually a good solution. Can I ask why you suggested this ahead of border-image?

Comment: sure - pseudo elements are like 'virtual' html elements; you can treat them similarly to any other html element + apply css in the same way. Using it over border image gives you so much more options. Remember to accept my answer if you found it useful!